# Encapsulate rxjs pipe into function

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I've been searching, but cannot find an answer to this.

Is there a way to encapsulate an rxjs pipe method into a custom method?

```
<observable>.pipe(
filter((num: number) => num % 2 === 0),
take(10)
map((num: number) => num * 10),).subscribe(...);
```

I'd like to reduce it to

```
<observable>.doSomeThingsThatArePiped().subscribe(...);
```

I know about custom pipeable operators to simplify what's in the pipe, but in my code I have  a set of operators that I use multiple times and would like to reduce it down as much as possible - including the pipe.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My original code was made generic, but here's what I've come up with for my real project that extends the Observable prototype.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

declare module 'rxjs' {
  interface Observable<T> {
      subscribeUntilDestroyed: (component: any) => Observable<T>;
  }
}

interface IDestroyNotifier {
  readonly destroyed$: Observable<boolean>;
}

function untilDestroyed(notifier: IDestroyNotifier) {
  return <T>(source: Observable<T>) => source.pipe(takeUntil(notifier.destroyed$));
}

Observable.prototype.subscribeUntilDestroyed = function (component) {
  return this.pipe(untilDestroyed(component));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourOperator(source: Observable<T>) {
    return source.pipe(
        filter((num: number) => num % 2 === 0),
        take(10),
        map((num: number) => num * 10)
    );
}
```

And use it like this:

```
observable.pipe(
  yourOperator
).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Comment: That does not fit my description. I know about pipeable operators. I want to encapsulate the whole pipe.

Answer (score -1):

you can encapsulate common chains in `pipe` like so:

```
function myCustomOperator() { // whatever parameters you need, if any
  return pipe(
    filter((num: number) => num % 2 === 0),
    take(10),
    map((num: number) => num * 10)
  )
}
```

then usage is simple:

```
<observable>.pipe(myCustomOperator()).subscribe(...);
```